# Помогите разобраться с горутинами

Tags: golang

Пытаюсь постичь понимание работы горутин, каналов и тому подобное. Задался вопросом могу ли я ускорить цикл!?
К примеру есть такая конструкция:

```
xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &users)
for i := 0; i < len(users.Shop[0].Offers[0].Offer); i++ {
        catalog := "./temp/" + users.Shop[0].Offers[0].Offer[i].VendorCode + "_L"
        for d := 0; d < len(users.Shop[0].Offers[0].Offer[i].Picture); d++ {
            go DownloadPhoto(users.Shop[0].Offers[0].Offer[i].Picture[d], catalog, tick.C, wg)
```

*В первом цикле я беру код, чтобы во втором цикле скачать фото в каталог.

Следующая конструкция:

```
xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &users)
go func(structCh chan struct{}) {
            defer close(structCh)
            for i := 0; i < len(users.Shop[0].Offers[0].Offer); i++ {
                catalog := "./temp/" + users.Shop[0].Offers[0].Offer[i].VendorCode + "_L"
                for d := 0; d < len(users.Shop[0].Offers[0].Offer[i].Picture); d++ {
                    results[users.Shop[0].Offers[0].Offer[i].Picture[d]] = catalog
                    }
                }
}(structCh)
<-structCh
for picture, catalog := range results {
    wg.Add(1)
    go DownloadPhoto(picture, catalog, tick.C, wg)
}
wg.Wait()
```

Во второй конструкции я попытался ускорить цикл и запихнуть все в map, после уже с map скачивать фото и сохранять в нужный каталог. Первый и второй вариант по скорости идентичны). Направьте на нужную логику. Полный код в main.go по ссылке https://github.com/sarff/XML_love_price Спасибо.

Comment: (1) На гигантском XML первый вариант может быть слегка быстрее за счёт того, что первые картинки начнут подгружаться ещё до завершения обхода XML, но смысла в этом нет. Во втором случае не нужно создание `results` оборачивать в горутину, потому что всё равно ты ничего параллельно не делаешь, только усложняешь программу. (2) Циклы по индексу - это не стиль Go. Лучше заменить на `for _, offer := range users.Shop[0].Offers[0].Offer {` и на `for _, picture := range offer.Picture {`

Comment: "Задался вопросом могу ли я ускорить цикл!?" - скорее всего нет, потому что у тебя всё равно всё упирается в загрузку картинок, а ты их уже сделал асинхронными. Обход цикла наверное можно было бы раскидать на несколько горутин (1я обходит первую четверть массива, 2я - вторую четверть, и т.д.), но разницу ты если и увидишь, то только на миллионах, а то и больше

Comment: за цикл спасибо - дельное замечание). Получается горутины лучше использовать когда функция выполняется неприемлемо долго или при работе с БД, сетью и тд

Comment: Горутины нужны когда (1) есть что исполнять параллельно (как раз такой случай, картинки можно грузить параллельно) (2) когда запускается потенциально долгий процесс, остановкой которого ты не управляешь (тогда спустя какое-то время ты можешь вернуть юзеру ошибку, даже если горутина всё ещё заблокирована/выполняется.) 2й случай как раз описывает БД и сеть.